JavaScript overwrites settings to make my image responsive (Adobe Animate Export)
I have created an interactive infographic with the help of Adobe Animate and implemented it to my website: Infographic on my Website Unfortunately I don't find a solution to make it responsive; it doesn't scale when I resize the window or view the graphic on my mobile phone.
Since the responsive function, which I was able to set in the "Publish Settings", only produced strange results, I tried to find another solution to make the graphic responsive.
To do this, I first switched off the EventListener, which overwrote my manually created width and height values when the window size was changed.
In theory, my solution now works: If I adjust the settings in the Chrome Developer Tools on a trial basis (width: 100%. height: auto), the reponsive adjustment of the image works perfectly in this preview.
However, if I then incorporate these changes into my website code, it does not work. The script simply overwrites my values when the page is loaded.
I tried to get the script to use my required values for width and height, but this also failed.
This script section:
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);

loads these values:
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '4A0DC7F22C54B9489C856D25CD90F5DC',
    width: 650,
    height: 2179,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    opacity: 1.00,
    manifest: [
        {src:"https://static1.squarespace.com/static/597c793a4c0dbf2d3c6a1490/t/66506af2b083c43608fd66c8/1716546290943/nabuinsekteninfografikelisabethdeim1500px.png", id:"nabuinsekteninfografikelisabethdeim1500px"}
    ],
    preloads: []
};

into this HTML section
HTML section:
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:650px; height:2179px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="2179" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:650px; height:2179px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>

If I adjust this section as follows in the Developer Tools in Chrome, the image can be scaled responsively without any problems:
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:650px; height:2179px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="2179" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:650px; height:2179px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>

Unfortunately, I can't find a solution for how I have to adapt the script so that this code is loaded at the end.
"width="715" height="2396" changes to width="650" height="2179" and ";width: 100%; height: auto;" changes to ";width: 650px; height: 2179px;" when I reload the page.
I hope someone of you has an idea or even a cleaner solution to make the graphic responsive.

What do your publish settings look like in Animate? Is it set to JavaScript/HTML? (It's been a while since I've used Animate, so I'm not sure what the settings look like now.)

In Adobe Animate I ticked in the publish settings:
Basic: Loop Timeline, Include Hidden Layers, Make responsive (by width), export image assets as Image assets
HTML/JS: ticked Overwrite HTML file on publish, hosted libraries, compact shapes
I have tried various settings under "Make Responsive". However, the result was always the same: the image is scaled to the HEIGHT of the screen. Only when I do not select "Make Responsive" is the image displayed correctly. I therefore decided to solve the problem outside of Adobe Animate.

Ah... yeah. I remember. They don't give many options. A couple of low-effort suggestions: turn on the responsive setting and just embed the html as an <iframe> in your html. That way you can control the size of the iframe from outside. Or try to see if you can use setTimeout to execute the script.

iframe is the easiest and best solution! You're right. This works perfectly! I placed it inside a div to make it responsive (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp)
